# Github Oauth tokens in Laravel - Move from BitBucket

Tags: laravel, github, heroku, composer-php, bitbucket

I moved a repo from bitbucket to Github. It is a Laravel app that is deployed on Heroku. I had a token in the auth.json like so ...

```
"github-oauth": {
    "github.com": "token"
}
```

I also created a heroku pipeline and a staging app. When I attempted to push to the staging app, the heroku build failed to get several of the composer dependencies and gave the error ...

```
Failed to download "x" Could not authenticate against github.com
```

Do I need to get a new oauth token because of the new staging app or is this related to the move from bitbucket to github? How do I go about getting this new token? Also, github complained about the presence of the token in the auth.json but bitbucket did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: as [described here](https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/languages-frameworks/php/#github-api),  GitHub’s API is rate limited.

Make sure your token is a [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new).

See "[GitHub App Caster](https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/pierredavidbelanger/githubappcaster)" as an example, and make sure you have:

- `GITHUB_API_LOGIN`: your GitHub login (username)
- `GITHUB_API_TOKEN`: a generated GitHub personal access token with the public_repo scope

That means at least:

```
$ heroku config:set GITHUB_API_LOGIN="your_username"
$ heroku config:set GITHUB_API_TOKEN="your_token"
```